Firebase hosted site will not send emails via sendgrid
I have a website built in React/Node.js where a user can submit a support ticket through a form on the website that will send me an email with the users message to me from my same email. This is created using sendgrid SMTP service. When testing on localhost, everything works just fine without issues. When testing on hosted site on firebase, the email never gets sent and sendgrid never registers the attempt even though firebase gives a 200 response. I have sendgrid setup to also send 'forgot password' emails and it works fine on hosted site (though it is not integrated the same way). The domain I bought was from Godaddy and it was setup with my firebase website. I have added the domain and my email that is both sending and receiving the messages to sendgrid authorization. No IP addresses are restricted at this time on sendgrid. At this point, I have no idea why it is not working.
TLDR;  I can send emails using sendgrid on my website hosted on localhost but not when hosted on  firebase despite no restrictions and authorized the email and domain on sendgrid. No errors appear.
